# multichose in phonebook android

Tags: java, android, multichoiceitems

I have one question. In my application I open the phonebook and pull out the name and number of the person you have chosen. Here is the code that I do:

```
public void showContactsChooser(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1001);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

        switch(reqCode){
            case (1001):
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                    Uri contactData = data.getData();
                    Cursor c = cr.query(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                    String phone = "";
                    if (c.moveToFirst()){
                        String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
                                "DISPLAY_NAME = '" + name + "'", null, null);
                        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            String contactId =
                                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                            //
                            //  Get all phone numbers.
                            //
                            Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId, null, null);
                            while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                                phone = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                                int type = phones.getInt(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
                                switch (type) {
                                    case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                            phones.close();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name + " " + phone, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.d("PICK", "Contact " + name + " " + phone);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In this piece of code I open the phone book and when you click on a contact name and get a phone number, then go back to the old Activiti. But I can only choose one person. And I need to choose a few. My question: 
**Can I choose a few people in the phone book and then pass them to the application. And how to do it?**

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there isn't any in-built way for selecting multiple contacts from contacts book!

What you can do is, fetch the contacts and display it in `RecyclerView` or `ListView` having custom adapter with checkbox. And then return those selected data back to your activity.

Comment: Yes, I am doing so, the app pulls contacts and add them to the list. However, if the contact has more than one number, it is duplicated, and if a lot of contacts is bad for me because I have friends in the application server, which are under contacts